# Can't find iso file to burn CD

Tags: wubi, iso, cd

I want to use Ubuntu to format an external HDD to EXT3, but not to run on my PC. I downloaded Infrarecorder and the windows installer download on the Ubuntu download page. after rebooting Infrarecorder shows up in my program list but not Ubuntu (although when re-booting I was prompted if I wanted to use Ubuntu or Windows as my OS). In my Ubuntu folder there is a zipped installation file, so apparently Ubuntu is not running on my PC. Should I unzip and install this file and then select the image file to burn on CD, or would I be better off uninstalling the windows version and downloading the desktop 12.04 LTS version?

I am using Windows XP SP3 as my OS and as imperfect as windows is I don't want to deal with conflicts on the PC if I load Ubuntu hence my caution.  Thank you

Comment: Why didn't you choose Ubuntu when prompted?

Comment: Should I have? I assumed this would open my PC using Ubuntu and not  in windows and that the wubi version was supposed to run on windows.

Comment: Just to be clear: You installed Ubuntu via the Windows Installer (Wubi) and upon restart you are greeted with the option to choose Ubuntu? The Windows Installer will not install Ubuntu so that you can use it _in_ Windows, it rather uses a kind of "safe mode" to install it more or less _alongside_ Windows, *you will still have to choose Ubuntu* when you boot your PC. Does Ubuntu really not show up in your programs list despite being installed properly as described here [WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide).

Comment: If you want to run Ubuntu inside Windows, install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or some other kind of virtualization software on Windows.

Comment: I just found another program EaseUS Partition that enabled me to format the external drive into EXT3 without having to go through any complications. Thank you for the input however.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear. You won't use windows installer to format the drive. Just download the iso and infrarecorder, burn it to a cd or dvd and put it in the cd drive. Restart the the sytem and choose try ubuntu option. After some time you can see the ubuntu desktop. Open diskutility and format the drive.